# TypeError connecting to tweetstream -- Python 3.2

Tags: python, twitter

Apologies, sure this is simple:

New to Python and to Python interfaces with Twitter's streaming API, trying to use tweetstream on Python 3.2 to do so.

```
import tweetstream
stream = tweetstream.FilterStream(username = "myusername", password = "mypassword", track = bytes("oprah", encoding = "utf-8"))
for tweet in stream:
    print(tweet)
```

Throws:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

I had encoded the 'track' argument because earlier attempts to pass a string threw,

TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str.

Thanks.

Comment: Is tweetstream compatible with python 3.2? If tweatstream ever does anything like u'thisisautfstring' then python3K is going to throw some errors. That said, where is the error getting thrown? I assume in the "stream=" line, but do you have the full traceback? That would be helpful

Comment: I just looked at the codebase, it seems to catch some python 3k stuff, but I think this is largely unimplemented. There's no urllib2 in python3k with no way of catching it

Comment: Got it, thanks. The full traceback was: File "<stsdin>", line 1, in <module> \n File "C:\Python...(location of tweetstream)...\streamclasses.py", line 165, in __iter__ \n self._init_conn() \n File "C:\Python...(location of tweetstream)...\streamclasses.py", line 86, in init_conn \n postdata = self._get_post_data() or {} \n File "C:\Python...(location of tweetstream)...\streamclasses.py", line 232, in _get_post_data \n if self._track: postdata['track'] = ",".join(self._track) \n TypeError:  sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are using Python3 with a Python2 package.

See here for information on Python3 bytes:

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#bytes

Also this:

http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals

In python3, this will send an array of bytes. However, `_get_post_data` function is expecting a string. The way strings are handled in python3 and python2 is totally different and the source of much frustration for those wishing to port to Python3.

Unless this package makes this compatible with Python3, you will need to use Python2. You could do it yourself of course, but considering any other package you will use will also be limited to using python2, I would recommend going that way.

Basically, in python 2.6/2.7, if you do

```
b = bytes('a')
print type(b)
```

you will get type str

In python 3, if you do

```
b = bytes('a')
print(type(b))
```

You will get type "bytearray"